# How to use Git for branches with very similiar code

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have a project in git and there are two branches that contain almost the same code. Basically they contain code for communicating with two versions of hardware unit. Most of the code is the same but there are differences because of changes in the underlying hardware.

For some other reasons we do not want to merge the two branches in one and do some "if versionA then something else if versionB then somethingdifferent...." constructs. So everytime we make "global" change we need to make it in both branches. This may be annoying but with help of TortoiseGIT and it's merge tool it is quick job to transfer the changes from branch to branch and I am afraid that there is no mechanism in git that could simplify this. But what I would like is to at least let git know (and show in log) that these two branches has been "conceptualy merged". Is there any way how to do this?

For the sake of completeness - it is a Delphi project but I do not think it is relevant to the problem.

Comment: Maybe you should move the common part into different project? http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: This is also an option but that would lead to more complicated class structure in the project and in this case we decided that it is not worth it (the project has already about 45 submodules :-) )

Answer (score 0):

I would track one of the branches from the other.

Create the branches:

```
git checkout -b b1 origin/master
git push origin HEAD
git checkout -b b2 origin/b1
git push origin HEAD
```

Now b2 tracks b1.

After updating b1 you can do this to rebase the branch specifics on b2 on a new version of b1:

```
git checkout b2
git pull -r
```

Comment: I will need to look more into this but one thing I am afraid of is that git will try to merge the branches and that could result in complete mess...

Comment: If if get it right this means that b2 would track changes in b1 but what if I would like to merge some work from b2 to b1. I could not probably simply do push instead of pull? And "cyclic" tracking is probably very wrong idea too :-)

Comment: Yes you would always update b1 and inherit the update into b2. Never the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

> But what I would like is to at least let git know 
>   (and show in log) that these two branches has been "conceptualy merged"

Git offer `git merge -s ours` for exactly this purpose.  This will create merge history, showing the branches having been merged, but won't change any content. From that point forward, you could then track changes to one branch but not the other fairly easily.

Note that I don't really think this is the best solution for you though, but all my normal workflow suggestions you are explicitly saying you don't want :)

-A

Comment: We use this technique for "feature-wise merge". You make branch to implement some new features and in this branch you do not care about code quality. When the code works, you merge it into a production-quality branch with the ours strategy and basically you create new code based on the "ugly" one (with a lot of copy/paste ofc). And I do agree that this workflow is not a good one however it works fine and one of the branches will be deprecated in some time, etc. So we do not want to put much effort into refactoring the code. I just wanted know if git can somehow log/show the branches relation.